# Why my useContext is not working in my code

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have just started learning useContext hook and I am struck in this problem.

I am not able use the hook itself when I am trying to print that in console its says undefined.

This is the App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import NoteState from "./Context/Notes/NoteState";
import About from "./components/About";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <About />
      <div>ankit</div>
      <NoteState>
        <About />
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
      </NoteState>
    </>
  );
}
```

These are the files where the hook is defined

```
    import { createContext } from "react";
    
    const noteContext = createContext();
    
    export default noteContext;


Second one is  

import React from "react";
import NoteContext from "./NoteContext";

const NoteState = (props) => {
  const state = {
    name: "Name",
    surname: "Surname"
  };
  return (
    <>
      <NoteContext.Provider value={state}>
        {props.childern}
      </NoteContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default NoteState;
```

I am trying to use this in `About.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import noteContext from "../Context/Notes/NoteContext";
import { useContext } from "react";
const About = () => {

  const a = useContext(noteContext);

  console.log(a); - >> comes undefined
  return (
    <>
      {/* <div>this is about note me but {a.name}</div> */} this gives error
    </>
  );
};
export default About;
```

You can see the same in this codesand box link.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bessie-x1y23s?file=/src/components/About.jsx:0-365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in your NoteState component. It should be `props.children` and not `childern`. When I made that change and ran your sandbox, it was working fine.

Comment: @Briserva: You might want to consider using React with Typescript. It's exactly the kind of bugs it would immediately highlight in the editor.

Comment: It would have but I am using codesandbox so no error hightlighting

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting as `noteContext` in Notecontext file, but importing as `NoteContext` in NoteState file.